# kotlin:android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #24

Tags: android, xml, inflate-exception

I want to add navigation drawer in my activity that has a recycler view

If you need other xml file codes, tell me to put it here.
**MainPageActivity.kt**

```
class MainPageActivity : AppCompatActivity(), NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener,CustomAdapter.OnItemClickListener {

    lateinit var toolbar:androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
    lateinit var drawerLayout: DrawerLayout
    lateinit var navView:NavigationView

    private var data = arrayListOf<UserModel>()
    private lateinit var myadapter:CustomAdapter
    private val gson = Gson()


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_page)

        toolbar =findViewById(R.id.toolbar)
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar)

        drawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout)
        navView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view)

        val toggle = ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,drawerLayout,toolbar,0,0)
        drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(toggle)
        toggle.syncState()
        navView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this)


        val recyclerview = findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.recycler_view)

        recyclerview.addItemDecoration(SimpleDividerItemDecoration(this)) // for insert line divider to recyclerview items

    }

    override fun onNavigationItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        when(item.itemId){
            R.id.nav_profile->{
                Toast.makeText(this,"profile clicked",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
            R.id.nav_message->{
                Toast.makeText(this,"message clicked",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
            R.id.nav_frinds->{
                Toast.makeText(this,"frinds clicked",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
            R.id.nav_update->{
                Toast.makeText(this,"update clicked",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
            R.id.nav_logout->{
                Toast.makeText(this,"logout clicked",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        }
        drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START)
        return true
    }

}
```

**activity_main_page.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/content_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:drawable/screen_background_light_transparent"
        tools:listitem="@layout/item_list" />

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
        app:menu="@menu/nav_menu" />


</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

I went ahead to create this navigation drawer according to the tutorials on YouTube
Because I am a novice in the field of Android, no matter how hard I tried, I did not find the cause of the problem
thank you

Comment: Can you include your `nav_header.xml` and `nav_menu.xml`?

Answer (score 1):

Well you are adding `recyclerview` in the drawerlayout here. This layout consists of two layouts which are included. One is `content_main` , this is the back screen layout and the other one is `NavigationView` with id `nav_view` which is for the sliding drawer layout. What you can try doing is adding the `recylerview` in the `nav_view` and you can add the menu options in the `recyclerview`. I haven't tried it but inside `nav_view` is where you can aim your efforts.

Comment: That's nice Edy, do share your solution here so that anyone in future can find that helpful as well